# Limit points and boundary points of a general metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let X be a metric space, E a subset of X, and x a boundary point of E.

It is clear that if x is not in E, it is a limit point of E.

Similarly, if x is in E, it is a limit point of X\E.

And there are ample examples where x is a limit point of E and X\E.

My question is: is x always a limit point of both E and X\E? I have looked through similar questions, but haven't found an answer to this for a general metric space. A counterexample would be appreciated (if one exists!)

Comment: Yes: the boundary of $E$ is also the boundary of $X \setminus E$

Answer (score 1):

$A=\{0\}$ (in the reals, usual topology) has $0$ in the boundary, as every neighbourhood of it contains both a point of $A$ (namely $0$ itself) and points not in $A$. But it is not a limit point of $A$ as neighbourhoods of it do not contain other points from $A$ that are unequal to $0$. You need isolated points for such examples.

If you mean limit point as "every neighbourhood of it intersects $A$", boundary points *are* limit points of both $A$ and its complement. But I gathered from your remarks that points in the boundary of $A$ but not in $A$ are automatically limit points that you probably mean the stricter definition that I used above.

Comment: Yes, the stricter definition. The weaker definition seems to miss some crucial properties of limit points, doesn't it? For example if we took the weaker definition then every point in a set equipped with the discrete metric would be a limit point, but of course there is no sequence (of distinct points) converging to it.

Comment: Being a limit of a sequence of distinct points from the set implies being a limit point of that set. The reverse does not always hold (though it does in first countable $T_1$ spaces, so metric spaces in particular). So I wouldn't call it a crucial property in that sense. It does correspond more to the metric intuition.